# Delete line from cv2.HoughLines array with special value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

I'm scanning a picture with opencv for lines. And according to the documentation every thing is working as planned.

```
lines = cv.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200)
for line in lines:
    rho,theta = line[0]
```

My pictures has to many lines and I only want to go on with the horizontal lines before doing the

```
for line in lines:
```

But because the entries are nested I couldn't find a proper solution to delete the elements.
All entries that have line[0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348269/numpy-delete-list-element-from-list-of-lists) = 0 should remain in the array lines.

I tried to modify the solutions of this thread [numpy delete list element from list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348269/numpy-delete-list-element-from-list-of-lists) but the elements are not in a list of list. The single elements are in a list of list.

Example: I want that the fourth element is the only that remains.

```
lines = ([[564.,1.57079637]],[[566.,1.57079637]],[[547.,1.57079637]],[[549.,0]],[[549.,1.57079637]],[[496.,1.57079637]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example `lines` is a tuple of nested lists. The return value of `cv.HoughLines`, however, is a numpy array of shape (n,1,2). To make a workable example for `cv.HoughLines`, we'll use `lines = np.array(([[564.,1.57079637]],[[566.,1.57079637]],[[547.,1.57079637]],[[549.,0]],[[549.,1.57079637]],[[496.,1.57079637]]))`.

You can use list comprehension:

```
lines = np.array([x for x in lines if x[0][1] == 0])
```

Result:

```
array([[[549.,   0.]]])
```

Comment: Sure, you're right. It is a numpy array. And your solution is working perfectly. Only you have to change the "!=" to a "==". THANK YOU!

Comment: oops, leftover from some trial, corrected it in the answer, thanks.